# New solution callable class PHP

Tags: php

a directory

```
|--root/
|--|----|core/
|--|----|app/
|--|----|----|controller/
|--|----|----|---------|SiteController.php
|--index.php
```

in file SiteController.php

```
class Sitecontroller
{
      public function __construct()
      {
          echo 'This is Site Controller';
      }
}
```

and now in file index.php, i want to call class SiteController look like this:

```
$control = new App_Controller_SiteController;
```

`App_Controller_SiteController` is alias path for function `__autoLoad`, somebody can help me?

Comment: If your class is called `Sitecontroller` then you cannot instantiate it with `new App_Controller_SiteController`. No no. The autoloader can include the file for you, but that's it. PHP will try look for the class `App_Controller_SiteController` to instantiate, which doesn't exist, which produces an error.

Comment: I think you may want to look into [Namespaces](http://www.php.net/namespace).